# ScrollView with GridView not scrolling to the bottom

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/verticalScrollView_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pets_for_sale_text">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/listing_GridViewLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        </GridView>
        <!--<View-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="400dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_below="@id/listing_GridViewLayout"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="0dp"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/simulate_bottom_margin_view" />-->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I tried many solutions including adding padding to `ScrollView` or to `LinerLayout` which does nothing. Also tried adding extra view on the bottom to create that extra padding, also does nothing. Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

(take a look at second grid picture to see what is the issue, 1st grid is the result I'm trying to achieve)

Comment: Change the height of your `ScrollView` to `match_parent`

Comment: Did you know you could achieve this layout with a single layout element? Use a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` instead. Also why have you wrapped your `GridView` inside a `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the solution that worked for me was to add "app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf" to the gridview so it stays on top of the toolbar displayed. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

set this inside your GridView layout element:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Comment: that didn't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your height of Scrollview to Match_parent